# In a dynamic ordered list in pure js, with <ol> and <li> tags as inputs, i cannot access properties of object inside array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, object, dom

i know a little about .map, .key, .hasownproperty, and .value, but trying to avoid them (didn't learned them in a class).

any idea for the "keep-it-simple-stupid" solution here?
thanks a lot.

```html
<html>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="firstname">
        <input type="text" id="lastname">
    </form>
    <button onclick="insertUser()">ins</button>
    <div id="myContainer"></div>
</body>
<script>
    let properties = [
        'firstname',
        'lastname',
    ]
    let users = []
    let form = document.querySelector('form')
    let myParent = document.getElementById('myContainer')

    function insertUser() {
        let user = {}
        for (let prop of properties) {
            user[prop] = form.elements[prop].value
        }
        users.push(user)
        form.reset()
        for (let i = 0; i < users.length; i++){
            console.log(users[i])//works, i see firstname and lastname
        }
        //console.log(users[0].firstname) works awesome
        for (let key in user){
            console.log(user[key].value)//gives me undefined in any possible variations
        }
    }
    /*
    myOl.innerHTML = "array item #"
    myLi.innerHTML = "object inside array value"
    myOl.appendChild(myLi)
    myParent.appendChild(myOl)
    */
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Change `console.log(user[key].value)` to `console.log(user[key])`.

Comment: thanks a lot! it works!

Comment: You're welcome :)